# VBA code to copy two sheet data in one sheet Simple modification required

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy my data of "Sheet 1" and "sheet 2" to "sheet 3"

I have the following code

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P100").Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

1. Now I want the copied data of sheet1 in sheet3 should be of BLUE color
2. After copying Shee1's data in sheet3, Sheet2's data will copy below to the Sheet1's data & of which Green color.
3. After copying both data in Sheet3 Column C will be sorted from smallest to largest.

Comment: You are confusing the audience again. I suspect the called sheets are those from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696512/vba-macro-to-copy-values-from-2-sheets-and-combine-the-data-in-another-sheet-as. But then the task is not worded correctly. The column meanings in `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are different. So simply copying one under the other will not be useful. The columns with the same meanings must be shifted to the same positions first.

Answer (score 3):

Try this short routine. You were copying the entire [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) so I will assume that you do not have columns header labels in row 1 that should **not** be copied.

```
Sub this_and_that()

    'clear Sheet3
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

End Sub
```

You gave no indication of the exact location to start pasting data in Sheet3 (defaulting to an [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) upon activating a worksheet is not precise) so I have elected to simple clear Sheet3 before the Copy & PAste.

Comment: Thanks Jeepad for your help, I want to start pasting the data in Sheet 3 from A4 onwards                                                                                      and I want to select certain range of data to be pasted from Sheet1 such as A1:P200 and certain range of data of sheet2 such as A1:J200 so what should be the code would be and sheet1 pasted color should Blue and sheet2 pasted color should Green

Comment: As an [enthusiast programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), I'm sure you will welcome the oppotunity to complete what I've started for you.

Comment: Yes but can you solve my problem which I have mentioned ??                               I want to start pasting the data in Sheet 3 from A4 onwards and I want to select certain range of data to be pasted from Sheet1 such as A1:P200 and certain range of data of sheet2 such as A1:J200 so what should be the code would be and sheet1 pasted color should Blue and sheet2 pasted color should Green

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test1()

  Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet

  ' This provides IntelliSense
  Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set Sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
  Set Sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

  Sh3.UsedRange.Clear

  Sh1.Range("A1:P100").Copy Sh3.Cells(1, 1)
  Sh3.Range("A1:P100").Font.Color = vbBlue

  Sh2.Range("A1:P100").Copy Sh3.Cells(101, 1)
  Sh3.Range("A101:P201").Font.Color = vbGreen

  Sh3.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Sh3.Cells(1, 3), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

End Sub
```

The above code works. Problem solved